# She always advances her agenda by malicious means

Tags: adjectives, word-difference

In the following sentence I for one prefer to use the adjective "malicious," but I wonder if you could tell me whether the bold adjective below alters the meaning of the sentence in which the word "malicious" is used or not:

> - She always advances her agenda by **malevolent** means.

Comment: You should include some aspect of the definition that makes you doubtful about using the word here. Why do you think **malevolent** might not be suitable?

Comment: You mean "alters" instead "ulters", right? Basically, you seem to ask about the difference between "malicious" and "malevolent", any specific reason for that?

Comment: If she has evil intentions and does not care if people get physically hurt then both are suitable.

Comment: Thank you very much @lurker. I just needed to know if these two adjectives differ in meaning and usage a lot or there is just a subtle nuance between these two words. Actually for me they both mean the same and I was not sure about the possibility of substituting the word 'malevolent' with 'malicious' in above sentence. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

They're largely interchangeable here:

> malevolent - having or showing a wish to do evil to others.
>
> malicious - characterized by malice; intending or intended to do harm.

I think there's a subtle difference that "malicious" suggests intending more specific harm, probably towards a specific person, particularly in revenge or from spite.  "Malevolent" suggests more general evil intentions.

"Malevolent" is not a common everyday word, and suggests something a bit more spiritual.  For an example of when "malevolent" would be appropriate but "malicious" would not, I think any example would be debateable, but if you're familiar with Lord of the Rings, I would describe Sauron as malevolent rather than malicious - he represents a general, spiritual evil, rather than just a specific harm.

Comment: Thank you @hugh; it was really helpful, but could you please tell me if it is possible to find a sentence in which just 'malicious' can be used and 'malicious' cannot. Actually I guess whereas 'malevolent ' covers a broader area of meaning, it can encompass the meaning of  'malevolent ' too; then there must be a situation in which just the word 'malicious' (which can convey a broader range of the meaning) can be used. In this manner I tend to realize the subtle nuance  between these two words.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to know if the words 'malevolent' and 'malevolence' in everyday (specially American) English or not? I guess these words are used very rarely at least in comparison with the word 'malicious'.